# Django Model field read only for a MySql generated column

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to add a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to a MySql database and am looking for a way to be able to read that column from a a Django model object, but not have it *ever* try to write a value for that column on an insert/update and MySql will throw an error on that.

I know that you can easily set a field to be readonly on a form for the admin site, but is there a way to set this at the model/field level?

Comment: You could give your field a "private name" like `_my_field` and create a getter (property) `my_field` for it without a setter. You can also override `__setattr__()` to throw an exception if someone tries to set it. But you still need to use raw sql in your migration file to create that column so it gets generated.

Comment: And that will prevent the ORM from ever trying to update the field when calling save()? Doesn't seem like that would be the case, but I suppose I could try it.

Comment: no it won't. By "... and MySql will throw an error on that" did you mean to say "otherwise MySql will throw an error" or "and I want an error to be thrown"? You could also override the model's `save()` method, calling its `super` method with `update_fields` always set to exclude this specific field.

Comment: MySql will throw an error if you try to insert/update a generated column value. I will check out the update_fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to override the default manager to return a `QuerySet` that is always annotated with the value from that column:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

class MyManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            my_field=RawSQL('''"{table}"."myfield"'''.format(
                table=self.model._meta.db_table
            ), ())
        )
```

then set `objects = MyManager()` in your model and whenever you fetch objects, they will be annotated with the field you want:

```py
instance = MyModel.objects.first()
instance.my_field  # value from db annotation
```

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick, thanks! Only complaint would be that `refresh_from_db()` don't seem to refresh this field, but I can probably live with that

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```py
def get_deferred_fields(self):
    deferred_fields = super(MyModel, self).get_deferred_fields()

    # Exclude MySQL generated columns, which cannot be saved
    deferred_fields.update({
        "my_generated_column_field1",
        "my_generated_column_field2",
    })

    return deferred_fields
```

Note: `get_deferred_fields()` is a public method and it can be overriden, but there may be unintented side effects. In my django app, it is only every called during `save()` and never during `refresh_from_db()`, but it could.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to add a method that does a raw SQL query.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/

Comment: How does that prevent the model from trying to set the field anytime you call save()?

Comment: I think @MarkBailey suggest to not create a field at all on the model, but a method/property that does the raw SQL query to fetch the value. It does mean one extra query each time you need to access it (you could use `@cached_property` to limit it to once per request).

Comment: Yes, @dirkgroten is right.  I wouldn't create a field for it at all, and as he says elsewhere you will have to create the SQL column manually.  I haven't actually done, this, but it's what I'd try.

Comment: Gotcha, doing an extra query every time does not scale and is therefore not something I am looking to do.

Comment: Also - it does not allow you to filter the query set by this field